# PHP/SQL - Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, fatal-error

I am fairly new to web programming but I know quite a bit. I am making a private messaging system but I am getting an error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\message\send.php on line 26
```

This is the code:

```
$check_conv=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `hash` FROM `message_g` WHERE (`user_one`='$my_id' AND `user_two`='$user') OR (`user_one`='$user' AND `user_two`='$my_id')");
```

What am I doing wrong, I have checked and there are values in the database. Also I have checked and I am using mysqli all around and not mixing mysql and mysqli. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Full code below:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$myusername=$_SESSION['myusername'];
$random=rand();
$my_id=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE (`username`='$myusername')");
$user=$_GET['user'];
$check_conv=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `hash` FROM `message_g` WHERE (`user_one`='$my_id' AND `user_two`='$user') OR (`user_one`='$user' AND `user_two`='$my_id')");
if(mysqli_num_rows($check_conv) == 1){
    echo "<p>Conversation Already Started!</p>";
} else {
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `message_g` (`user_one`, `user_two`, `hash`) VALUES ('$my_id','$user','$random')");
    echo "<p>Conversation Started!</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: this line of code have no issue, it is not in this line that your issue is, maybe in the line where you are using $check_conv

Comment: well nobody can tell you what's wrong just seeing this line of code, no magicians around, just programmers :)

Comment: Yes, but what does the error mean.

Comment: You are doing something that is trying to turn the object into a string, and you can't do that.  But we don't know because you aren't showing us the line of code that had the problem.

Comment: That is actually the line of the code that had the problem, it says line 26, and I showed you line 26.

Comment: it is using `$my_id` inside the $check_conv query your issue, `$my_id` is a mysqli_result not an integer

Comment: So i need to convert $my_id to an integer before putting it into the query?

Comment: you can't convert a result into integer, you have to fetch the result. check my answer.

Comment: @poseidon: You need to understand that `mysqli_query` returns an object, not an integer, not a string.  If that does not make sense to you, **stop and read the manual**.

Comment: Thanks for the help, in future I will read the manual first, I understand that it returns and object and not a string firstly and that I have to save it as a string first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try fetching your mysqli_result, at the place of using directly in the query

```
$my_id_query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE (`username`='$myusername')");
//Fetch result 
$my_id_array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($my_id_query);
$my_id=$my_id_array['id'];
//Cast this into int to protect yourself against sql injection
$user=(int)$_GET['user'];
$check_conv=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `hash` FROM `message_g` WHERE (`user_one`='$my_id' AND 
`user_two`='$user') OR (`user_one`='$user' AND `user_two`='$my_id')");
 if(mysqli_num_rows($check_conv) == 1){
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_query` returns an object.  You can't just print the object.  You need to read the mysqli documentation to learn what to do with the results of an mysqli_query object.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: I am not printing it though, after that I am checking the rows.

Comment: How do we know that?  We can't see your code?  You showed us one single line of code.

Comment: Will add rest, one minute.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem.  Here you go and do a query and assign it to $my_id, thinking that you are getting the actual value from the column, but you aren't.

```
$my_id=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE (`username`='$myusername')");
```

Then you try to interpolate it into a string in your second call:

```
$check_conv=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `hash` FROM `message_g` WHERE (`user_one`='$my_id' AND `user_two`='$user') OR (`user_one`='$user' AND `user_two`='$my_id')");
```

For that to work, $my_id would have to be a string, but it is not.  It is an object.

---

Also, unrelated to your problems here, please note that **by building SQL statements with outside variables, you are leaving yourself open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. My site http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has many examples in detail.

Comment: THanks for the tips, would give you rep if I could.